# collect the value returned by netstat into a variable

Tags: shell, scripting, unix

netstat -an | grep hypen echo $variable hypen | wc -l

How to collect the value of **netstat -an | grep `echo $variable` | wc -l**
to a varibale conn_count.

Comment: @all, ` | wc -l` after `grep`  should of course be `grep ... -c`, see the useless use of `wc -l` award: http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#wc

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks for maximum portability:

```
conn_count=`netstat -an | grep ${variable} | wc -l`
```

If you have a more modern shell such as bash, you can use `$()` instead:

```
conn_count=$(netstat -an | grep ${variable} | wc -l)
```

`$()` notation is better because it is easier to nest:

```
foo=$(netstat -an | grep $(head /path/fo/foo))
```

Comment: $variable="abc|efg|xyz    rst|ghf|tcg"
for i in $variable
do
Conn_count=$(netstat -an | grep $(echo ${i} | cut -d'|' -f3) | wc -l)
done

want to find the netstat of the third field and collect it to a varible

Answer (score 1):

Use the subshell "backticks" escape, if you want to be able to use it for sh, ash, and variants thereof:

```
thevariable=`netstat -an | grep echo $variable | wc -l`
```

If you will be guaranteed access to bash or zsh, you could use the `$()` syntax instead:

```
thevariable=$(netstat -an | grep echo $variable | wc -l)
```

I think the first one also works with (t)csh, but I'm not sure as I don't use them.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it for each value between pipe characters:

```
variable="abc|efg|xyz rst|ghf|tcg"
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS='|'
for i in $variable
do
    Conn_count=$(netstat -an | grep "$i" | wc -l)
done
IFS=$saveIFS
```

This will do it for only the third value:

```
variable="abc|efg|xyz rst|ghf|tcg"
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS='|'
i=($variable)
IFS=$saveIFS
Conn_count=$(netstat -an | grep "${i[2]}" | wc -l)
```

Or, using `read` (`IFS` doesn't need to be saved):

```bash
variable="abc|efg|xyz rst|ghf|tcg"
IFS='|' read -r field1 field2 field3 remainder <<< "$variable"
Conn_count=$(netstat -an | grep "$field3" | wc -l)
```